# i keep getting Attempt to read property "id" on null from the code below which is located in my controller

Tags: php, laravel

i keep getting the error from this code

```
//insert into orders table
        $order = Order::create([
            'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
            'date' => Carbon::now(),
            'address' => $request->address,
            'status' => 0
        ]);
```

If you need to see any other code from my files to help me please tell me

Comment: look like auth()->user() is null try dd(auth()->user()) before order creating.

Comment: it shows null, i don't know why

Comment: you have to loggin to get auth()->user() or else it will be null

Comment: Does this happen during an api request?

Comment: been so stressed, didn't notice that i wasn't logged in, thanks

Comment: Simply it means auth object is empty, you are not logged in.